# Naming convention for parameters with/without, causing confusion bugs?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, naming

I have two parameters in a class called:
**textWithHeader** and **textWithoutHeader**
and they are very confusing names!
adding the fact that the get method is getTextWithoutHeader() + the IDE autocomplete it's pretty easy the mixed between them.

In a few places in the code, some developers got mixed between them causing some really difficult bugs in the systems.

Is there any naming convention for this type of parameters?

Good, but no cigar:

- changing to **text** and **textWithHeader** is not explicit enough.
- changing to **headerlessText** and **TextWithHeader**, will put them not next to each other on autocomplete which I would like to preserve.

Comment: it's called "common sense". if you don't understand the difference between 'with' and 'without', the problem is not with the naming. How you name your variables is up to you and your colleagues, this is not something the "community" dictates.

Comment: Why not just name them `text` and `textWithHeader`?

Comment: maybe a single method getText(boolean withHeader) ?

Comment: @Stultuske it's not that I don't understand the meaning, it just that with auto complete it's easy yo get mixed between them.

Comment: How about `text` and `headerAndText`?

Comment: @dorony then don't use autocomplete. this is not 'confusion between names', this is a side-effect of being lazy

Comment: @Stultuske being lazy is not addressing this issue, I understand that you don't see any issue here, but for a non native English developers it can be.

Comment: @dorony English is my 4th language. the problem with autocomplete (and relying there on) is that people just assume that the "first choice is the right one". if you (and your colleagues) are non-native english developers, and you are not cooperating with people that have a different native language, why not name the variables in your own language? if you do need clarification for other developers, you can always add documentation explaining it for them.

Comment: @Stultuske we are a multi language company. I agree with what you say on the fact that people just assume that the "first choice is the right one". And this is why I am changing the names :)

Comment: @dorony be that a solution as it may, it is just a temporary one. sooner or later, you'll find yourself in similar issues. so, my recommendation: make variable names unique and (immediately) recognizable. but this is an in-house convention you should decide on (with your team(s))

Comment: `textOnly`. But this seems largely opinion-based - you've already discarded the most logical (not opinion-based, if obvious) suggestions.

Comment: Honestly, “easier to choose in autocomplete” is one of the worst design motivations I have ever heard.  I agree with Stultuske: developers who can’t be bothered to discern fields that already have clear, meaningful names are just lazy.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest calling them **headerlessText** and **textWithHeader**
You keep the meaning, but the names are different enough, not to confuse.

Comment: I still want the names to start with the same word so they will appear next to each other on auto complete. but nice suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Well they don't *look* confusing: to me at least.

They follow Java's "camelCase" conventions for variables and are sufficiently descriptive. There's not much else you can do.

Although if you want to stop implicit conversion of the two things you could always wrap them in separate classes:

```
class TextWithHeader
{
    public final String s;
}

class TextWithoutHeader
{
    public final String s;
}
```

Perhaps then, your `TextWithHeader` class could even provide a method `getTextWithoutHeader()`?

Comment: they are two parameters in the same class with get methods